# How can i import a view controller on a uiview controller?

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, subview

May be it will a stupid for someone but i need the solution of this problem.I want to add a view controller on another view controller.If I explain it then,

1. My main view controller is containing a uitableview.
2. My another view controller containing a scrollview of buttons.

Now I want to set my scrollview controller at the top of the my main view controller [which is taking uitableview]. Thats mean [mainview addsubview:scrollview controller]

**NOTE THAT: My scrollview is a view controller which is taking scrollview of some buttons.**

If somebody give any example or source code or link of tutorial on these problem then it will very much helpful for me.

Thanks In advance.

**EDIT:**

Till now i have done...

In .h file

```
#import "scrollViewButtons.h"
scrollViewButtons *scrollButtonView;
@property (nonatomic,retain) scrollViewButtons *scrollButtonView;
```

In .m file

```
@synthesize scrollButtonView;
```

In `viewDidLoad`

```
scrollButtonView = [[scrollViewButtons alloc] initWithNibName:@"scrollViewButtons" bundle:nil];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 43);
scrollButtonView.view.frame = frame;
scrollButtonView.view.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
[self.view addSubview:scrollButtonView.view];
```

Now i can see the scrollButtonView in my main view but i can not find any user interaction.I can not scroll the scrollview of buttons.Can anybody tell me why i am not being able to interact with that scrollButtonView?

Comment: Anybody else please review my question and it answer and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing views with view controllers. Apparently you have two views that have separate view controllers and you and you want these views to appear inside another view. That's very easy to do.

If you have a view controller, such as firstVC, then you can add the view that it controls by adding that view to another view, such as bigView. just use

```
[bigView addSubview:firstVC.view];
```

If you have a second view controller, such as secondVC, then you can add the view that it controls by adding that view to the another view, bigView. just use

```
[bigView addSubview:secondVC.view];
```

Now you only need to manage the view bigView with a view controller.

You can vary this, depending on your level of understanding and the level of complexity or simplification you want to have.  Most view controllers managed several UIViews -- like labels, buttons, text fields, and other views. However, you may instantiate a second view controller (secondVC) inside the first view controller (firstVC) and then add the view of secondVC into the view of firstVC, like this:

```
[firstVC.view addSubView:secondVC.view];
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply. I am trying these,if i face any complication then i will knock you.Thanks again.

Comment: I have import button scrolview controller now when i want to use your suggestion `[bigview addsubview:srollviewButtons.view]` then it shows me `property view not found on object of type 'scrollViewButton'`
`

Comment: What class is scrollViewButton? And do you have an extra 's' or a missing 's' in the name of the instance? (scrollViewButtons or scrollViewButton)

Comment: Ok i am explaining it fully....`#import "scrollViewButtons.h"` in .h file then in .m file `[self.view addSubview:scrollViewButtons.view];`

Comment: Can you show the content of the scrollViewButtons.h and .m files? It would be easier to see why a property is not found if you could show these.

Comment: I have edited my question can you tell me where is the problem?

Comment: Still don't see the scrollViewButtons.h and scrollViewButtons.m files.

Comment: I have solve my problem when i use this `[self.navigationController.view addSubview:scrollButtonView.view];`   Whatever thanks for your patience.